# How to insert local like button in JSP pages?

Tags: jsp

I want to make an art gallery and insert like button below the uploaded pictures.I want to make the like buttons in such a way so that the local registered users and like/dislike those pictures.
So suggest code based on JSP(Servlets) that can be deployed on Eclipse(IDE).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find here people that will help you, but this site has rules. You are supposed to do some research, try some code and then ask precise questions showing your efforts. You should first read [ask], and edit this question to make it conform to SO rules or delete it and ask a correct one later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location = 'yourServlet'" src="yourLikeImage.png">Like</button>
```